# Add a new tomcat(worker) to a existing cluster made using Apache server and mod_jk without having to restart Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, java, mod-jk, tomcat7

I have set up cluster for loading balancing for the two different tomcat that are running on different machines using Apache Server and mod_jk. I have configured workers.properties and everything seems to be working fine that is one by one the requests are being sent to different tomcats.

Now, if I want to add the third worker (worker3/Tomact3) without restarting apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reloading Apache instead?

If you need automatic Tomcat node discovery, you might want to have a look at [mod_cluster](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, reloading of the apache works, but it is what something I cannot do. I must not bring down the server, so restarting apache is not a solution.

Yes, I am actualy looking for somekind of automatic tomcat node discovery, i will look a mod_cluster and see how it goes.

Thanks again.

Comment: Reloading httpd is not the same as restarting httpd. With a reload, all existing sessions will remain active. New connections from clients will be spawned using the new config.